# Is the collection of arithmetic means of a dense subset of $[0,1]$ a dense subset of $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $\{ q_i \}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a dense subset of $[0,1]$. Define the arithmetic sample mean of the sequences $\{ q_i \}$ by
$$ m_n := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n q_i .$$
Question : **is $\{ m_n \}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ also a dense subset of $[0,1]$?**
Because $\{q_i \}$ is dense, then there always exists subsequences of $\{q_i \}$ converging to any $x \in [0,1]$, but does this property carry over via the arithmetic mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily. Let $q_i$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]\setminus\{0.5\}$ with the property that for any $n\in\mathbb N$, $q_{2i}=1-q_{2i-1}$.

Observe then that $m_{2n}=0.5$ for any $n$. And, $m_{2n+1}=\frac{n+q_{2n+1}}{2n+1}$. Thus, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}m_{2n+1}=0.5$ regardless of enumeration.

Thus, $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}m_n=0.5$$This implies that the only limit point is $0.5$.

Comment: I prefer this to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

No. It is easy to bias these arithmetic means by a suitable ordering of the $q_i$, simply by choosing, say, ten elements in $[0,\frac12]$ for every single element in $(\frac12,1]$.

An explicit ordering would be quite messy, but I hope you get the idea.